# JavaFX java.lang.NoSuchMethodException and Instances cannot be created by FXML Loader Errors

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm new to JavaFX. I've been hunting for answers to these two issues all day. The two fixes I found for the NoSuchMethodException were to make sure the TableView had an fx:id and to make sure it had a constructor without parameters. Made sure I had both of those two things fixed.

The instances cannot be created by FXML Loader shows up when you uncomment the two Inhouse lines in the FXML. I didn't post the full code files because they are huge.

FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="partTable" styleClass="dataTable">
                        <columns>
                            <TableColumn text="Part ID">
                                <cellValueFactory>
                                    <PropertyValueFactory property="id" />
                                </cellValueFactory>
                            </TableColumn>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" text="Part Name">
                                <cellValueFactory>
                                    <PropertyValueFactory property="name" />
                                </cellValueFactory>
                            </TableColumn>
                            <TableColumn text="Inventory Level">
                                <cellValueFactory>
                                    <PropertyValueFactory property="instock" />
                                </cellValueFactory>
                            </TableColumn>
                            <TableColumn text="Price/Cost per Unit">
                                <cellValueFactory>
                                    <PropertyValueFactory property="price" />
                                </cellValueFactory>
                            </TableColumn>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                                //<Inhouse name="Part 1" price="5.00" instock="5" max="10" min="1" />
                                //<Inhouse name="Part 2" price="7.00" instock="2" max="11" min="2" />
                            </FXCollections>
                        </items>
                        <sortOrder>
                            <fx:reference source="nameColumn" />
                        </sortOrder>
                    </TableView>
```

Controller

```
@FXML
TextField inhouseTextField;
@FXML
TextField outsourcedTextField;
@FXML
private TableView<Inhouse> partTable;
@FXML
private TextField partNameField;
@FXML
private TextField partInstockField;
@FXML
private TextField partPriceField;
@FXML
private TextField partMaxField;
@FXML
private TextField partMinField;
@FXML
protected void addInhouse(ActionEvent event){
    ObservableList<Inhouse> data;
    data = partTable.getItems();
    data.add(new Inhouse(partNameField.getText(),
            Integer.parseInt(partInstockField.getText()),
            Double.parseDouble(partPriceField.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(partMaxField.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(partMinField.getText()),
            Integer.parseInt(inhouseTextField.getText())
            ));
    partNameField.setText("");
    partInstockField.setText(String.valueOf(partInstockField));
    partPriceField.setText(String.valueOf(partPriceField));
    partMaxField.setText(String.valueOf(partMaxField));
    partMinField.setText(String.valueOf(partMinField));
    inhouseTextField.setText(String.valueOf(inhouseTextField));
}
```

Class

```
public class Inhouse extends Part {
Integer machineID;

Inhouse(){

}

Inhouse(String text, int parseInt, double parseDouble, int parseInt0, int parseInt1, int parseInt2) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

Wall of Errors:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$280/709942340.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
at    com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ims.AddPartController.addInhouse(AddPartController.java:76)
... 56 more
```

Comment: Not quite sure exactly what the question is here. Are you asking why you get the null pointer exception (in which case you need to tell us which line is throwing the exception, which value is null, and why you think it shouldn't be null), or are you asking why you get the `NoSuchMethodException` when the lines in the FXML file are uncommented (in which case uncomment those lines and post the stack trace you get from that exception).

Comment: Why do you do this `partInstockField.setText(String.valueOf(partInstockField));`? This sets the text to something like this: `TextField@14f6e983[styleClass=text-input text-field]`. Keeping the value in the fields does not require any code BTW. The exception you've posted does not contain a `NoSuchMethodException` and is caused by one of your fields not being injected. FXMLLoader shouldn't even load the fxml file since `//` is not a valid comment in xml. Furthermore `FXMLLoader` requires the constructor it uses to be `public` which is probably the issue your question is about...

Comment: you have to specify what it is **Part** otherwise I can not do any tests

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, but I don't think I fully understand what I'm asking. It seems like the Instances cannot be created error wasn't actually an error since the code is working fine with it. Is it possible to delete this thread? If not, that's okay. I just need to figure out what exactly it is I need help with before I ask another question.